# How does jQuery's modification of an object's pseudo-class CSS work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-selectors

How does jQuery's modification of an object's pseudo-class CSS work?

Does it manipulate the stylesheet through [DOM Level 2's insertRule](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/css.html#CSS-CSSStyleSheet) method?

The reason I ask the question is that I'm trying to modify an element's `:hover` CSS property using jQuery and it just isn't happening:

```
$("input.generated-button:hover").css("background-image", "-moz-linear-gradient(top, red, blue)")
```

If I use `insertRule` myself, though, it works:

```
document.styleSheets[0].insertRule("input.generated-button:hover" { background-image: -moz-linear-gradiant(top, green, blue); }", 0);
```

Comment: "How does jQuery's modification of an object's pseudo-class CSS work?" It does?

Comment: Maybe I should've asked how it's supposed to work :)

Comment: It shouldn't work as you intend. The `css` method will apply to whatever is returned by the selector `input.generated-button:hover` right now -- it won't be delayed... it won't wait for the hover event.

Comment: @J-P jQuery is supposed to support all of the CSS 1-3 selectors and, since many of the pseudo-classes don't exist yet, I expected them to be handled differently.  However, you're probably right.  That's the problem... There is no `input.generated-button:hover` when I use the jQuery selector, so it doesn't have anything to apply the CSS to.

Answer (score 2):

As @J-P pointed out, jQuery finds the element with the given selector in the document as it is when the code runs.  Since there aren't any elements with the `:hover` pseudo-class when the code runs, it can't find anything to apply the CSS to.

Effectively, jQuery doesn't support `:hover`, or any of the other CSS classes that only exist under certain circumstances.

I could probably do something with [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live), but that would defeat the purpose.

Comment: These are some of what's known as dynamic pseudo-classes: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#dynamic-pseudos